# Change text length to either one of two values based on drop down option selected

Tags: excel, vba, validation

In addition to the question I posted previously, ([Change text length based on drop down option selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559895/change-text-length-based-on-drop-down-option-selected)), I have another scenario where a Bank's account numbers (BANK C) are either 10 or 15 digits long. The answer to my previous question facilitated changing the text length to a range (between 10 and 15 digits) and changing the text length to exactly 12 digits, by creating a lookup table and defining the min and max values.

I was told that a different approach would be needed to change the text length to either one of two values (meaning either 10 or 15 digits), but nothing I've tried so far has worked.

---

As shown in the last question:

I am using the following table:

[image]

I am using the following formula in my Data Validation:

```
=AND(LEN(B2)<=VLOOKUP(A2,F:H,3,FALSE),LEN(B2)>=VLOOKUP(A2,F:G,2,FALSE))
```

VLOOKUP will only return the first line and I need it find multiple so I can test against those.

---

How can I go about getting this to work, while still allowing the other two ways to work?

Comment: I cannot come up with any reliable method that will work with Data Validation.  The only thing I can think of is a work around.  One would create a unique name `Bank C (10)` and `Bank C (15)`.  It is the only way I can come up with.

Comment: "*change the text length*" meaning you want the displayed format to be `"0000000000"` or `"000000000000000"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe slightly different approach as shown below. Validation rule formula seems working to me:

```
 =NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(LEN(C3),OFFSET($G$4:$G$9,,MATCH(B3,$G$3:$I$3,0)-1),0)))
```

We are just checking if we can find length in specific column in the table. Possible values means all possible lengths. You can also build your table horizontally, but this will require some formula adjustments. If you want, you can either expand Range G4:G9 and G3:I3 or change it to named range, or try referencing to column and header of table - these solutions will make our validation formula flexible (when you add item to list, formula will change automatically). 
I am pretty sure that it is also possible to simplify that formula.
I'm sorry for cutting row numbers in the screenshot.

[image: solution]

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly and much neater than my original formula below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following formula worked for me:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(1, A4)), AND(LEN(B4)>MIN(9), LEN(B4)<MAX(16))), TRUE,  IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(2, A4)), LEN(B4)=12), TRUE,  IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(3, A4)), OR(LEN(B4)=10, LEN(B4)=15)), TRUE,FALSE)))
```

[image]

So basically if "1" is found in cell A4, where the drop-down list of all the bank names is, it will only allow between 10 and 15 characters to be entered into cell B4 (where i'm inputting the bank account number). If "2" is found in cell A4, it will only allow 12 characters to be entered and if "3" is found in cell A4, only 10 OR 15 characters can be entered. Thanks for the replies though everyone.

Comment: Nice try, but obviosuly when our bank list rules is static, otherwise it's not easy flexible (the formula needs to be modified every time we're adding new rule). Regards